# Powershell script run task scheduler will not start photoshop

Tags: windows, powershell, server, taskmanager

I have this command in a powershell script file. When I run the script from the powershell, it'll start photoshop and do some scripted things before photoshop quits it selves.

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2018\Photoshop.exe" -Wait
```

But when I run the powershell script with windows task scheduler, it doesnt start photoshop at all.

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\path\scriptPS1"
```

The task is running as my own user.

Comment: Is your scheduled task set up like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953926/how-to-execute-a-powershell-script-automatically-using-windows-task-scheduler)?

Comment: Yes it is. I have more commands in the script file. And they work fine. Its just that photoshop will not open or start.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked off "Run whether user is logged on or not", it worked.

I managed to find this out when i created a single task in the task scheduler that only started Photoshop by it self. And when I turned on the "Run whether user is logged on or not", the task scheduler was unable to start photoshop.

[image]