# Powershell Stop-Process Many Instances

Tags: powershell

I have a remote access program that does not clean up after itself after it is closed. In Task Manager, I oftentimes find 5 to 10 instances of the program running. For instance:

- XYZ.exe
- XYZ.exe
- XYZ.exe
- XYZ.exe
- XYZ.exe

I have a simple Powershell script to stop these processes, but the problem is I want to close n-1 out of n processes.

```
> Stop-Process -Force -Name XYZ*
```

kills n out of n processes.

Is there a way to kill all processes of a program while leaving open the newest (e.g. XYZ.exe #5)?

Comment: Use ' Get-Process -name firefox | sort ID' to list them ordered by ID. Then you need to enumerate them and delete all apart the last one. And then add an '| Stop-Process' at the end

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get-Process` to discover all matching processes ahead of time, then simply remove one of them before killing the rest:

```
Get-Process -Name XYZ* |Select -Skip 1 |Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate it so I can run it, say at 1 am, with a scheduled task?

Comment: [Sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953926/how-do-i-execute-a-powershell-script-automatically-using-windows-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it closes all non responding processes

```
Get-Process -name XYZ.exe| Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Responding -eq $false} | Stop-Process
```