# How to stop Powershell credential request from prompting in a long script?

Tags: powershell, office365

rather new to PowerShell and Office365 cmdlets.

Currently I've created a script which gets all the e-mail addresses from my Office365 service (around 140,000).  After it has retrieved all the emails using get-mailbox cmdlet I use the get-mailboxStatistics cmdlet to get the Last-Logon-Date.  It outputs all of this to a CSV file so I end up with an e-mail address that users last-logon-date.

The script is currently running as intended but a PowerShell Credential Request will randomly prompt after the script has been running. From what I've seen it will prompt completely randomly, sometimes it takes hours to prompt and other times it takes only 10 minutes.  The script is meant to run about once a year which will be scheduled,  I don't want to have to manually run it and re-enter in my details every time.

I've looked around and can't find anything to solve my problem. Office 365 Login Code below.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $arg -AsPlainText -Force
$msolcred = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $username, $password
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $msolcred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
    Import-PSSession $Session
```

Notes: 
-I'm pretty sure there is no loss of connection on my end.
-The script will most likely take around 10 hours in total to run.

If anyone needs further details feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you can use is to reconnect after X number of records have been processed. In the code below a new connection will be made after 1000 records have been processed.

```
# Save credential to a file
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml credentialFile.xml

# Load credential
$credential = Import-Clixml credentialFile.xml

# Set reconnect threshold
$reconnectThreshold = 1000

foreach($element in $array)
{
    # Reconnect if threshold is reached
    if($processedCount -ge $reconnectThreshold)
    {
        # Close all sessions
        get-pssession | Remove-PSSession -Confirm:$false

        # Start a new session
        Import-PSSession $(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection)

        # Reset processed counter
        $processedCount = 0
    }

    # Action on an item
    Action-Item $element

    # Increment processed counter
    $processedCount++
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are scheduling this by calling powershell.exe, use the `-NonInteractive` switch. This will throw an error instead of prompting, but that's something you can presumably `Catch` and deal with programmatically.

Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172234/3905079

Comment: I'll add -NonInteractive to my script and try and catch it correctly.  I'll let you know how I go.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran the following powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File 'C:\myFile'.

No luck unfortunately. Still getting prompted.  I'm running this in Windows powershell

Comment: Looks to me that it's the msol-service that's prompting you for those logins.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Username = "XXXX@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
$password= "xxx@12345"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, 
          $secureStringPwd
```

Comment: Whilst this code may be useful it would be much better if the answer explained how it works and how it solves the question.