# Powershell script not running on Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, powershell, task

I have a PS script that opens Excel (Com Object), processes a bunch of information, re-saves, and then sends some critical information via e-mail. The script runs great, and when I run it from the Run Console, it works great as well. However, when I schedule it as a task in the Task Scheduler it is not working properly. The task seems to "successfully run" every single time, but I do not get the output e-mail that I am supposed to get. I have run many other PS Scripts without a problem using the same configuration in the task scheduler. Could this have something to do with opening Excel as part of a script scheduled? Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Does the PS script need to run as an administrator?

Comment: Alternately, is the script trying to access something on network drives?  Try adding some basic logging to the script.  Is the script running under credentials that don't have the authority to send mail from or to the addresses used in the script?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney - Yes, and it is running as Administrator. I am running it with the same settings as any other PS script.

Comment: @BaconBits It is trying to access something on network drives...But it can access it without a problem when I Run from the Run Console in Windows. Does it make sense that the problem is only present when ran from Task Scheduler?

Comment: Background tasks don't get network drives because the Task Scheduler uses Session 0 isolation.  [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/937624) is a KB article describing it, and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx) is a good blog explaining the issue (among others).  You *may* be able to get around the issue with UNC paths, but if you're using administrative shares like `\\remotesystem\C$\[...]` you can still run into problems, IMX.  Configuring an actual share and configuring permissions will let you use UNC paths.

Comment: Also  Excel (Com Object) will not execute as a background task. It requires an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using the answer from @briantist in [PowerShell script won't execute as a Windows scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015245/powershell-script-wont-execute-as-a-windows-scheduled-task/65205431#65205431), but I wanted to isolate exactly which switch was solving the problem.

It had nothing to do with `-ExecutionPolicy`, `-Noninteractive`, `-NoLogo`, `-NoProfile` or any other system privilege, user account running the script, etc.

Just needed to add `-File` in front of the script path in the `Task Scheduler > Actions > Arguments` field. Without this switch PowerShell was launching and the task history was showing `Action Completed`, but the script was not executing.

Comment: Please avoid pasting an answer across multiple questions. If the questions are duplicates, flag them as a duplicates.