# Call multiple webpages from one powershell scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduler

**Aim--**
I need to call multiple webpages in a single powershell windows scheduler.

**current implementation--**

[image]

in 'Add arguments' section :

```
-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(\"https://example1\")"
```

**Output needed--**
I have to call more than two webpages here. How can i do that?

Purpose is - I have multiple webpages to call and i don't want to create separate scheduler for every webpage.

Comment: Make a script and call that script with the scheduled task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, scripting worked! nothing else.
I was avoiding to make a script, just wanted to do it with scheduler only.

But anyways, here are the linkes which helped me-
[How to setup a Powershell Script in Windows Task Scheduler with admin permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245797/how-to-setup-a-powershell-script-in-windows-task-scheduler-with-admin-permission)

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-your-first-powershell-script-file-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "@('https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1','https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/2') | ForEach-Object {(Invoke-WebRequest `$_).Content}"
```

Comment: Getting an error. Invoke-WebRequest : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
At line:1 char:99
+ ... ode.com/2020/day/2') | ForEach-Object {(Invoke-WebRequest `$_).Conten ...
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], UriFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: PS C:\Users\alHaos> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: I checked. it is working with powershell. But it is not working with windows scheduler.  I tired changing path to open powershell app in scheduler, still giving me error. Any idea for this one ?